# Is it possible to write a file (e.g. pdf) to the iPad (locally) using JavaScript in xcode?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, file, local-storage

So far I have a html link running javascript code, but I am unsure what to do next.

Basically I want to:

1. Press hyperlink
2. Run JavaScript Code
3. Read File
4. Write File to local directory on the iPad

Here is my code so far:

```
<a id="mylink"><img src="../assets/images/research/Download.jpg"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var a = document.getElementById("mylink");
        a.onclick = function() {
            console.log("WORKED");
            //here is where it will read/write the file
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have seen a lot of examples in objective c with webview, but I have tried these and it messes up the layout of the app.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with it one it's saved?

Comment: The user will then be able to open it locally using ibook etc.

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode?

Comment: I am making an ios app in xcode with phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide in the Apple Docs for [Creating a PDF File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-CJBHHJCB)

The code listing for MyCreatePDFFile provides code for saving out a CGRect to a PDF.  I've adapted this into a UIView+PDF category in the past.

Comment: I cant use webview, the app is already finished other then this small section, and if I use webview it messes up the layout of the app which I dont have time to sort out, thanks though.